# Oracle SQl Developer - Combining multiple rows into one row based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to write a SQL query that would normally return multiple rows into one row depending on some conditions. Below is an example and desired results.

The query only returns the START & AGMTNUM when all the ACCTNUMs associated with that AGMTNUM are in Active STATUS.

table name Customer_Setup
Example

```
Start      AGMTNUM      ACCTNUM      STATUS
12/1/16    AAAA         123456       ACTIVE
12/1/16    AAAA         789012       ACTIVE
12/1/16    AAAA         345675       PENDING 
7/1/16     BBBB         444444       ACTIVE
7/1/16     BBBB         555555       ACTIVE
8/1/16     CCCC         666666       PENDING
8/1/16     CCCC         777777       PENDING
8/1/16     CCCC         888888       PENDING
9/1/16     DDDD         999999       ACTIVE
9/1/16     DDDD         000000       ACTIVE
```

Expected results

```
START     AGMTNUM
7/1/16     BBBB  
9/1/16     DDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
select start, agmtnum
from t
group by start, agmtnum
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'ACTIVE';
```

It is unclear whether `start` is part of the definition you want.  You might want this slight variation:

```
select min(start), agmtnum
from t
group by agmtnum
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'ACTIVE';
```

Comment: I'm getting multiple rows for each ACCTNUM per AGMTNUM when the status of each is ACTIVE.  I'm looking for the query to return just one row per AGMTNUM when all the ACCTNUM STATUS are Active.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
select distinct "Start", agmtnum
from
  customer_setup c1
where
  not exists ( select * from customer_setup c2 where c1.agmtnum = c2.agmtnum and c2."STATUS" <> 'ACTIVE')
order by 1;
```